# Metasploit is not detecting newly imported python exploit

Tags: exploit, metasploit, python

I have added `OpenSSH 7.2p2 - Username Enumeration` exploit to Metasploit, which is a python exploit. But after so, it does not detect that exploit every way I tried.

I have placed it under the directory `/.msf4/modules/exploits/linux/remote` and made it executable. Then I ran the command `updatedb`.

In my locally placed exploit-database it was under the directory `exploits/linux/remote`.

Before adding it there were 1822 exploits in Metasploit, after adding the new one it should have got increased, but it remained the same. It does not detect the new one.

I have also tried running `msfupdate`, I thought updating the whole framework could change something. But its all the same.

**Version**

I'm running metasploit v5.0.0-dev-39aff8d.

I have installed it from https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework.git

**OS**

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

..
..
..

Some minimum clue would mean great help. Thank you.

Comment: I think this could be better answered on metasploit's github. Anyway, can you provide a link for the module you are trying to import?

Comment: I tried creating an issue in github, but for some reason the 'submit' button there remains disabled, once I find a solution for that I will post there. 

And sure, here is it, 

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40136/

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking the link you provided on comments to the exploit you are trying to import on Metasploit, I must say that it is not compatible to Metasploit. I mean, the script you are trying to import never is going to work on Metasploit. This is the link you provided on the comments: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40136/

Metasploit now has the feature to import python modules, that's true but it is not able to import any python script. The script must have a structure. A python script that can be imported to Metasploit should follow these rules: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Writing-External-Python-Modules

Bear in mind that the module must be able to "talk" to Metasploit interface. There is a couple of links you can read about how to deal with it:

http://www.primalsecurity.net/python-for-metasploit-automation/

https://www.optiv.com/blog/scripting-metasploit-with-python

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for such a detailed informative answer and your time. It will help me a lot, I will have thorough read for sure. Thanks again.

Comment: I just marked it now. :-)